# работа с базой данных на удаленном пк

Tags: c#, база-данных, .net, visual-studio, файлы

Всем здравствуйте! у меня есть .NET Framework приложение, которое использует базу данных. У меня компьютере все работает хорошо, но вот на чужом пк работать не будет, так как я в `App.config` прописываю расположение моей базы данных:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
  </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
  <add name="IpAddresses" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=H:\PingIPApp\PingIPApp\IpAddresses.mdf;Integrated Security=True"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

На чужом пк соответственно путь к базе будет другой, и я подумал что перед перед использованием базы данных нужно будет сначала найти ее местоположение и затем изменить его в `App.config`:

```
            string fileName = "IpAddresses.mdf";
            FileInfo f = new FileInfo(fileName);
            string fullname = f.FullName;

            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IpAddresses"].ConnectionString = fullname;
            connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IpAddresses"].ConnectionString;

            sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
```

но при запуске приложения, получаю это исключение:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: "Конфигурация только для чтения."
```

и как же тогда быть? нужно как-то на ходу поменять путь, а то программа просто не найдет мою базу данных...

Я пробовал еще так:

```
            string fileName = "IpAddresses.mdf";
            FileInfo f = new FileInfo(fileName);
            string fullname = f.FullName;

            sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(fullName);
```

но получаю эту ошибку при запуске:

```
System.ArgumentException: "Формат строки инициализации не соответствует спецификации, начиная с индекса 0."
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, кто может - буду очень благодарен!

Comment: Это так не делается и вам не поможет. Ставьте полноценный SQL сервер и обращайтесь к нему по по его IP-адресу. Либо ставьте на каждый компьютер локально и у каждого компьютера будет своя собственная база.

Comment: Здравствуйте, A K! спасибо за Ваш комментарий!